# Concating fields and removing trailing whitespace in one line

Tags: perl

I have a string with 3 fields separated by whitespace. I would like to concat the 2 last fields with `-` making sure that the newline in the end is removed.

The following works:

```
echo -n "abc 1234 5679" | tr -s "" |cut -d ' ' -f2 -f3 | tr " " "-"
```

I was wondering if there is a `perl` onliner for this?

Comment: Why do you need `perl` for this?. There is no  new line character in your string shown

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best
 way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
printf 'abc 1234 5679' | awk '{printf "%s", $2"-"$3}'
```

or `perl`'s `awk` mode (`-a`):

```
printf 'abc 1234 5679' | perl -ape '$_ = "$F[1]-$F[2]"'
```

Note that both would remove the line delimiter if present, if you want to preserve it if it's there, with GNU `awk`:

```
printf 'abc 1234 5679\n' | gawk '{printf "%s", $2"-"$3 RT}'
```

With `perl`:

```
printf 'abc 1234 5679\n' | perl -ape 's/.*/$F[1]-$F[2]/'
```

Comment: I want to be sure that the new line delimiter and possibly any trailing whitespace removed

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
$ echo -n "abc 1234 5679" | perl -pe 's/(\d+)\s+(\d+)$/$1-$2/'
```